# TextInput field not showing value inside Map function react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

value is not displaying inside 'Textput field' while passing dynamic content inside value 'prop'

```
const [arrayList, setArraylist]= [
         {id:0, ExpectedQuantity:10, DeliveredQuantity:7},
         {id:1, ExpectedQuantity:19, DeliveredQuantity:9},
         {id:2, ExpectedQuantity:11, DeliveredQuantity:11},
         {id:3, ExpectedQuantity:45, DeliveredQuantity:30},
     ]

arrayList.map((items,index)=>{ 

     return
            <TextInput  value={items.DeliveredQuantity} />

})
```

Comment: Please show more code where use arrayList

Comment: If you are using react material ui, try setting defaultValue :        <TextField defaultValue={items.DeliveredQuantity} />

Comment: Please show the code of your entire component.

Answer (score 0):

Sample solution with react-material-ui
Note: as per your above snippet,

`useState` is missing which can cause errors

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiTextField-root": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "25ch"
    }
  }
}));

export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [arrayList, setArraylist] = useState([
    { id: 0, ExpectedQuantity: 10, DeliveredQuantity: 7 },
    { id: 1, ExpectedQuantity: 19, DeliveredQuantity: 9 },
    { id: 2, ExpectedQuantity: 11, DeliveredQuantity: 11 },
    { id: 3, ExpectedQuantity: 45, DeliveredQuantity: 30 }
  ]);

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div>
        {arrayList.map((items, index) => {
          return <TextField defaultValue={items.DeliveredQuantity} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```